# gdal.translate() for loop outputs intial file 12 times rather than compressing into 12 individual files

Tags: gdal, compression

```
# loop over min and max x and y coordinates
translate_options = gdal.TranslateOptions(format = 'GTiff',
                            creationOptions = ['BIGTIFF=YES','PREDICTOR=2' 'COMPRESS=LZW'])

for i in range(xdiv):
    for j in range(ydiv):
        xmin = xsteps[i]
        xmax = xsteps[i+1]
        ymax = ysteps[j]
        ymin = ysteps[j+1]
        
        print("xmin: "+str(xmin))
        print("xmax: "+str(xmax))
        print("ymin: "+str(ymin))
        print("ymax: "+str(ymax))
        print("\n")
        
        #gdal translate to subset the input raster
        output = gdal.Translate("uncompressed_tile"+str(i)+","+str(j)+".tif", ds , projWin = (xmin, ymax, xmax, ymin), xRes = res, yRes = -res, options=translate_options)      
        
        #gdal.Warp("uncompressed_tile"+str(i)+str(j)+".tif", ds, 
        #outputBounds = (xmin, ymin, xmax, ymax), dstNodata = -9999)              

                
                              
#Close the open dataset!!!     
ds = None
```

I have tried using **gdal.Translate()** to split an original file into 12 smaller files that are compressed, however the initial file is the output with a different name.

Comment: Should that not be srcwin not projwin?